# Delete a queue job outside of a worker in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I understand the listener passes a Job instance to my worker and i can use that instance to delete the job, but how can i delete a job outside of worker? 
Consider this scenario:

```
$job_id=Queue::push('DoTheJob', array('data'=>array(1,2,3)));

If(!someotherjobdone){
// delete job from Queue  with job_id
?
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Here's one way to do this depending on your Queue driver:

    $sqs_instance=Queue::getSqs();
    $sqs_instance->delete($job_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is correct, but I think you want to 'pop' the job off the queue:

```
$job_id=Queue::push('DoTheJob', array('data'=>array(1,2,3)));

If(!someotherjobdone){
    Queue::pop($job_id);
}
```

If that doesn't work you could try:

```
$queue=Queue::getQueue($job_id);
Queue::pop($queue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am implementing SQS Queue. If I have the 'ReceiptHandle' of the message (an ID associated with a specific instance of receiving the message), I can delete it by accessing the SqsClient object through the SQSManager, because the manager is accessible by the IoC container.

```
$queue_manager = App::make("queue");
$sqs_queue = $queue_manager->connection('sqs');
$sqs_client = $sqs_queue->getSqs(); 
$sqs_client->deleteMessage(['QueueUrl' => $queue_url, 'ReceiptHandle' => $receipt_handle]);
```